# Which tool to use to design an android Point of sale? In Android

Tags: android

I want to design a  Point Of Sale system on android, but I need to know layout allows me to list items with various details, (eg price, quantity, name, barcode)[image]

Something like this image
[image]

Comment: Please tell me this is homework.

Comment: I'm wondering from where you have picked this screen shot because this screen shot is from the app on which I worked. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.posimplicity

Answer (score 0):

Use [TableLayout](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_table_layout.htm) or [CustomListView](https://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/dynamic-listview-in-android/)